# Comparing two identical Double value return false Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to compare two identical latitude, which is of type `Double`, and when I print the result, it's evaluated as `false`.

```
print("spot latitude: " + String(spot.location.latitude))
print("first object: " + String(firstSpot.location.latitude))  
print(spot.location.latitude == firstSpot.location.latitude)
```

Output:

```
spot latitude: 32.8842183049047
first object: 32.8842183049047
false
```

Anyone has any idea what's going on?

Comment: It works for me. I checked it in playground. But try to convert those values on `Double` type of variable and then check.

Comment: Then the numbers are probably *not* identical. Try `print(spot.location.latitude.debugDescription)` which prints the number with higher precision.

Comment: Remove String (value), print directly the value i.e spot.location.latitude & firstSpot.location.latitude and check

Comment: @MartinR, it turns out that using `debugDescription`, the output is `32.884218304904714`
`32.884218304904707`

Comment: ... which means that the numbers are different. Problem solved.

Comment: That's not what I expected. Not sure how Swift handles the Double precision.

Comment: Where do the numbers come from? Why do you expect them to be equal? Are there any calculations involved which might "loose precision"? – Compare also [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: First I fetched some geo data from Foursquare api. then I saved it using parse to database. Later on, I just compare it again the new fetching version to the one I stored in the database, probably somewhere in between I somehow lost the precision.

Answer (score 36):

Comparing equality in doubles rarely gave you the expected answer this is due to how doubles are stored. You can create custom operators, keeping in mind that you should work with sort of accuracy.
To know more you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values), even if it speaks about ObjC the principles are super valid.
Since I had the same problem checking online I've found this [answer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25990) on the apple dev forum. 
This function should do the trick, you can easily create a custom operator:

```
func doubleEqual(_ a: Double, _ b: Double) -> Bool {
    return fabs(a - b) < Double.ulpOfOne
}
```

I've tried to convert from swift 2.x to 3.x it seems that the macro `DBL_EPSILON` is not available anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Comparing double or float values with == will not give the expected result in most programming languages, which means that numbers that you think should be equal are in fact slightly different. Instead compute the absolute difference and handle the numbers as equal if the difference is below some threshold. See [Compare double to zero using epsilon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698927/compare-double-to-zero-using-epsilon) for more explanations.

Comment: I would rather just let Swift itself handle it, simply using `String(spot.location.latitude) == String(firstSpot.location.latitude)` Thanks.

Comment: I would not say that *"comparing with == fails"*. It correctly evaluates to false if the numbers are different.

Comment: Kesong Xie: you can surely do that (all depends on your use case), but you will thus decide that locations that are different by less than a millimeter are not the same.

Comment: Martin R: you are right, I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 8):

## Swift 5, 4

Probably solution with rounding is best choice to get close values:

```swift
extension Double {
  static func equal(_ lhs: Double, _ rhs: Double, precise value: Int? = nil) -> Bool {
    guard let value = value else {
      return lhs == rhs
    }
        
    return lhs.precised(value) == rhs.precised(value)
  }

  func precised(_ value: Int = 1) -> Double {
    let offset = pow(10, Double(value))
    return (self * offset).rounded() / offset
  }
}

// values retrieving
a: 64.3465535142464, b: 64.3465535142464
    
// values debug description
a: 64.346553514246409, b: 64.346553514246395

// calculations
a == b // false
a.precised(10) == b.precised(10) // true
// or
Double.equal(a, b) // false
Double.equal(a, b, precise: 10) // true
```

If using amendment with epsilon, anyway I get false equal with doubles:

```swift
// values retrieving
a: 64.3465535142464, b: 64.3465535142464

// values debug description
a: 64.346553514246409, b: 64.346553514246395

// calculations
a == b // false
a - b  // 1.4210854715202e-14
a - b < .ulpOfOne // false
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this extension

```swift
extension FloatingPoint {
    func isNearlyEqual(to value: Self) -> Bool {
        return abs(self - value) <= .ulpOfOne
    }
}
```

or according to [this guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)

```swift
extension FloatingPoint {
    func isNearlyEqual(to value: Self) -> Bool {
        let absA = abs(self)
        let absB = abs(value);
        let diff = abs(self - value);

        if self == value { // shortcut, handles infinities
            return true
        } else if self == .zero || value == .zero || (absA + absB) < Self.leastNormalMagnitude {
            // a or b is zero or both are extremely close to it
            // relative error is less meaningful here
            return diff < Self.ulpOfOne * Self.leastNormalMagnitude
        } else { // use relative error
            return diff / min((absA + absB), Self.greatestFiniteMagnitude) < .ulpOfOne;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think because your two Double numbers are actually different.
When you convert Double to String in decimal number, rounding can't be avoided due to floating point representation. Even if two Strings look the same, actual numbers can differ. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648479/invalid-float-value-swift-3-ios#40649201) for more detail.

You can examine two numbers further by specifying more digits with:

```
print(String(format: "%.20f", double_number))
```

Answer (score 3):

Merging different `Swift 4` technics together:

```swift
import Foundation

infix operator ~==
infix operator ~<=
infix operator ~>=

extension Double {
    static func ~== (lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Bool {
        // If we add even a single zero more,
        // our Decimal test would fail.
        fabs(lhs - rhs) < 0.000000000001
    }

    static func ~<= (lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Bool {
        (lhs < rhs) || (lhs ~== rhs)
    }

    static func ~>= (lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Bool {
        (lhs > rhs) || (lhs ~== rhs)
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
// Check if two double variables are almost equal:
if a ~== b {
    print("was nearly equal!")
}
```

> **Note** that `~<=` is the fuzzy-compare version of less-than (`<=`) operator,
> And `~>=` is the fuzzy-compare greater-than (`>=`) operator.
>
> Also, originally I was using `Double.ulpOfOne`, but changed to a constant (to be even more fuzzy).
>
> Finally, as mentioned on my profile, usage under `Apache 2.0` license is allowed as well (without attribution need).

### Testing

```swift
import Foundation
import XCTest
@testable import MyApp

class MathTest: XCTestCase {
    func testFuzzyCompare_isConstantBigEnough() {
        // Dummy.
        let decimal: Decimal = 3062.36
        let double: Double = 3062.36
        // With casting up from low-precession type.
        let doubleCasted: Double = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: decimal).doubleValue

        // Actual test.
        XCTAssertEqual(decimal, Decimal(doubleCasted));
        XCTAssertNotEqual(double, doubleCasted);
        XCTAssertTrue(double ~== doubleCasted);
    }

    func testDouble_correctConstant() {
        XCTAssertEqual(Double.ulpOfOne, 2.220446049250313e-16)
    }
}
```

Comment: @SimonMoshenko after converting to Decimal, simply too much precession is lost (at least more than `Double.ulpOfOne`), so using a bigger constant will fix that. see update ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4.1:

I found a solution, that works pretty well for me. It is **flexible**, because you can **define** the "precision" for the comparing by passing the **number of fractional digits** that should be regarded and made it an extension of Double.

Lets say we have two values for example:

- value01 = 5.001 and
- value02 = 5.00100004

These values are considerd "equal" when only 3 fractional digits are regarded, but regarded es "not equal" regarding 8 fractional digits.

```
extension Double {

    /// Compares the receiver (Double) with annother Double considering a defined
    /// number of fractional digits.

    func checkIsEqual(toDouble pDouble : Double, includingNumberOfFractionalDigits : Int) -> Bool {

        let denominator         : Double = pow(10.0, Double(includingNumberOfFractionalDigits))
        let maximumDifference   : Double = 1.0 / denominator
        let realDifference      : Double = fabs(self - pDouble)

        if realDifference >= maximumDifference {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: But that is only for fractions, floating precision is also not exact when there are no fractals. Take for example the the Double numbers `let d1: Double = 200000000000000001` and `let d2: Double = 200000000000000000`. `d1 == d2` returns `true`. Your code does ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner with flexible precision. Works well for money

```
extension Float {
  func compare(with number: Float, precision: Int = 2) -> Bool {
    abs(self.distance(to: number)) < powf(10, Float(-precision))
  }
}
```

Example

```
let float1: Float = 0.1
let float2: Float = 0.2

(float1 * float2).compare(with: 0.02) // TRUE
(float1 * float2).compare(with: 0.02, precision: 1) // TRUE
(float1 * float2).compare(with: 0.02, precision: 3) // TRUE
Float(0.021).compare(with: 0.02) // TRUE
Float(0.021).compare(with: 0.02, precision: 3) // FALSE
(float1 * float2).isEqual(to: 0.02) // FALSE
```

Answer (score -3):

Please follow the below-updated code

```
    var a = -21.5
    var b = 305.15

   if(a.isEqual(to: b)){
     print(a)
   } else {
     print(b)
   }
```

Output

```
//prints 305.15
```