# How to get indexes of duplicates by parameters with O(n) in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, dictionary

I need to find duplicates by rounded coordinates and store the indices, then remove elements from the original array by these indices. How can I do this with O(n) ?

```
func removeDuplicate(from points: [Point]) -> [Point] {
    var originalPoints: [Point] = points
    let tempRoundedPoints: [Point] = roundingCoordinates(for: points)
    guard tempRoundedPoints.count > 2 else { return originalPoints }
    var removableIndexes: [Int] = []
    for i in 0..<tempRoundedPoints.count - 2 {
        for j in i + 1..<tempRoundedPoints.count - 1 {
            if (tempRoundedPoints[i]?.lat == tempRoundedPoints[j]?.lat) && (tempRoundedPoints[i]?.lng == tempRoundedPoints[j]?.lng) {
                removableIndexes.append(i)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    removeWith(indexes: removableIndexes, from: &originalPoints)
    return originalPoints
}
```

Comment: Is it important to retain the order of the input array?

Comment: If the order isn't important, you might be able to use `Dictionary.grouping(_:by:)`, where key would rounded value. if it's important, you could use an `OrderedDictionary`, populating it by iteration, where key would be the rounded location, and value the real location if order is important.

Comment: @Paulw11 I think not. The main thing is the result.

Comment: @Larme Сan you give an example in the answer, because I tried through the dictionary and I got porridge. I think I missed something.

Comment: If the order isn't important and it isn't mandatory to call `removeWith` then I would create the array of rounded values, create a `Set` from that array and then convert the set back to an array. `==` needs to be defined correctly on `Point`

Comment: @Paulw11 The set will remove duplicates from the array with rounded coordinates, but I need to get the indices and remove them from the original array. Perhaps I did not understand your idea, then it would be cool to see an example.

Comment: Ok.  I see now what you want

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic function to get the indices of duplicates in an array. It requires that the array element conforms to `Equatable` and `Hashable`. It uses a `Set` to store the duplicate values and returns an `IndexSet`.

`contains` called on a `Set` is much faster than called on an `Array`.

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable & Hashable, Index == Int {
    func indicesOfDuplicates() -> IndexSet {
        var index = startIndex
        var items = Set<Element>()
        var result = IndexSet()
        while index < endIndex {
            let currentItem = self[index]
            if items.contains(currentItem) {
                result.insert(index)
            } else {
                items.insert(currentItem)
            }
            formIndex(after: &index)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Call the function on the array

```
let indexSet = points.indicesOfDuplicates()
```

To remove the items in an array at indexes in an `IndexSet` efficiently see [removeObjectsAtIndexes for Swift arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173565/removeobjectsatindexes-for-swift-arrays/50835467#50835467)

Another problem is that identical `Double` values are not equal due to the *imprecise* nature of [floating point representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). You could use this extension found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911229/comparing-two-identical-double-value-return-false-swift-3)

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    func isNearlyEqual(to value: Self) -> Bool {
        return abs(self - value) <= .ulpOfOne
    }
}
```

Comment: Given solution in my case returns 0 indexes. I did hash by lng, lat and comparable by id. What could be the problem? I need specifically to compare lng, lat.

Comment: Yes. Your `==` function should be something like `return lhs.lat == hrs.lat && lhs.lng = rhs.lng }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's for reference:

```
var targetPoints = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6]
print("target result: \(targetPoints)")

var roundingPoints = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 5]
print("what we got: \(roundingPoints)")

func sort(arr: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let sortedArr = arr.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
    return sortedArr
}

roundingPoints = sort(arr: roundingPoints)
print("sorted array: \(roundingPoints)")

var index: Int = 0
for i in 0...roundingPoints.count - 1 {
    if roundingPoints[index] != roundingPoints[i] {
        index += 1
        roundingPoints[index] = roundingPoints[i]
    }
}

print("result: \(roundingPoints[0...index])")
```

ps. you can post in .playground and try it, hope the answer will help :)

I think the time complexity is O(n log(n)) + O(n)